# Can I tell if --jobs is used inside a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to set some variables based on whether or not parallel builds are enabled, so I tried this:

```
jobs:
»·echo "executing jobs job"

ifneq (,$(findstring -j,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
»·$(warning "parallel!")
else
»·$(warning "not parallel!")
endif
```

And this is what happens:

```
$ make -j2
Makefile:2: "not parallel!"
echo "executing jobs job"
executing jobs job
```

I also tried testing `$(JOBS)`, but no luck.

**Is there a way for me to tell inside a Makefile that the --jobs parameter was used?**

---

Additional info:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to know this?

Comment: The build currently does some nifty debug logging that breaks when done in parallel.  I want to enable/disable this debugging information based on if the build is done in parallel or not.  E.g. instead of the `$(warning)` I would set `enable-debug=1` or `enable-debug=0`.

Comment: Now I'm curious about your nifty debug logging and how it breaks. Also if you've seen the new output sync stuff in make 3.82 and 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, `${MAKEFLAGS}` will only gain the `-j` when it is expanded at recipe expansion time.

Makefile:

```
$(warning [${MAKEFLAGS}])

.PHONY: all
all:
    $(warning [${MAKEFLAGS}])
    echo Now do something useful
```

Run:

```
$ make -j5
1:1: []
1:5: [ -j --jobserver-fds=3,4]
echo Now do something useful
Now do something useful
```

Answer (score 1):

About the `MAKEFLAGS` expansion in @bobbogo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22948940/5771861): If we look at the code I think I can explain the behavior:

Looking at the code, `main` function of make calls the [define_makeflags](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/main.c?id=0c5a9f9b92af1634dc60fa21e9ac86ed50e5d595#n3103) function several times.

```
/* Define the MAKEFLAGS and MFLAGS variables to reflect the settings of the
   command switches.  Include options with args if ALL is nonzero.
   Don't include options with the 'no_makefile' flag set if MAKEFILE.  */

static struct variable *
define_makeflags (int all, int makefile)
{
......
```

Call locations in `main`:

[1)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/main.c?id=0c5a9f9b92af1634dc60fa21e9ac86ed50e5d595#n1909)

```
 /* Set up the MAKEFLAGS and MFLAGS variables for makefiles to see.
    Initialize it to be exported but allow the makefile to reset it.  */
 define_makeflags (0, 0)->export = v_export;
```

[2)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/main.c?id=0c5a9f9b92af1634dc60fa21e9ac86ed50e5d595#n2121)

```
 /* Set up MAKEFLAGS and MFLAGS again, so they will be right.  */

 define_makeflags (1, 0);
```

[3)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/main.c?id=0c5a9f9b92af1634dc60fa21e9ac86ed50e5d595#n2254)

```
 /* Set up 'MAKEFLAGS' specially while remaking makefiles.  */
 define_makeflags (1, 1);
```

There are other calls in sub-functions but this should be enough to explain.

The first call sets `all` parameter to false. The others set to true. With  `all` set to false, the `define_makeflags` function only parses "simple flags" and `j` is not one of them. In order to understand the parsing one needs to look into this [switch](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/main.c?id=0c5a9f9b92af1634dc60fa21e9ac86ed50e5d595#n3150) statement and the [definition of command line params](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/main.c?id=0c5a9f9b92af1634dc60fa21e9ac86ed50e5d595#n419).

My SWAG is like the following:

I presume the parsing of `ifneq` statements happen after the first call to `define_makeflags` but before the subsequent calls. I can guess the reason of keeping the `MAKEFLAGS` simple at the start is to continue to support documented Makefile patterns like the following.

From [doc1](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_7.html#SEC74), [doc2](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Testing-Flags.html):

```
archive.a: ...
ifneq (,$(findstring t,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
        +touch archive.a
        +ranlib -t archive.a
else
        ranlib archive.a
endif
```

If `MAKEFLAGS` contained long options or options that take parameters, then searching for single char flags in `MAKEFLAGS` would not be possible.

There is some guesstimate in my answer. Maybe someone who was involved in the design decision can also weigh in. Given this [change](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/main.c?id=fa0f2c516a3ba325db90a1b4657eebd3a9d82f97) Paul Smith may have an idea.